# this._removeListenerFns.pop(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli, angular-universal, angular14

I'm working on Angular 14 with angular universal version 14.2.3
The project is running fine but when tried to run `npm run prodbuild` I get the following error

this._removeListenerFns.pop(...) is not a function.

No other errors are occurred during the build process.
I'm attaching the package.json file as well for reference

```
{
  "name": "customer-angular-14",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run universalAngular:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/universalAngular/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run universalAngular:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run universalAngular:prerender",
    "prodbuild": "npm run prerender && npm run compress",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration production --aot && ng run universalAngular:prerender:production --no-guess-routes --routes /",
    "gzipper": "gzipper",
    "compress": "gzipper compress ./dist"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.1",
    "@miaguila/common": "^10.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.2.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@sentry/angular": "^7.7.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.7.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gzipper": "^5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "lato-font": "^3.0.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.3",
    "ng-payment-card": "^0.0.8",
    "ngx-card": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "sessionstorage": "^0.1.0",
    "signature_pad": "^4.1.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.23",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "universal-analytics": "^0.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.17",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.17",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

[This is the error message I get when routes are being rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyaUG.png)